# Sonar Plugin for Eclipse, not able to map JSP files for Sonar Analysis

Tags: eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, eclipse-indigo

I have a Sonar desk setup and an Eclipse (Indigo) IDE setup. I have integrated Sonar with Eclipse and have deployed my code base on Sonar and have run my desk setup on Eclipse.

The model(java) part of the Project is visible on the Eclipse in the Sonar plugin. this means that in the Sonar Perspective, i am able to view each and every file with analysis.

The problem comes in the JSP part of the View(Web). the language used to deploy the view on Sonar was web. the deployment was successful. The issue comes up when i try to view the analysis of the JSP in the Eclipse IDE through the plugin. the JSP files are never able to show their analysis in the sonar perspective where as i can see the same in the Sonar server.

Please suggest if there is any way to see the same in Eclipse. also if any one has worked on this. please share any issues/constraints that you might have faced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar Eclipse currently works only for the Java language, so this is normal that you can't see results for JSP files when you are running an anlysis with the "web" language.